# Git: fatal:The current branch XXX has no upstream branch (but it HAS the upstream branch)

Tags: git, push, branch

We use git + Jira + Bitbucket.

Scenario:

1. In Jira I've created (with `Create branch` option) branch `XXX`.
2. In Bitbucket I see that the branch `XXX` is appeared in the list of branches.
3. Make changes in the code => `git commit`.
4. `git push` gives: `fatal: The current branch XXX has no upstream branch.`

Question: what is the reason of this error? The branch `XXX` **has** the upstream branch (I see this upstream branch `XXX` in the Jira.)

Please note: before this error I've used `git push` with NO additional arguments.

UPD0: @RadioSilence has suggested to use `git branch -vv` command! I did and it helped me to see that "the local branch is not tracking the upstream". And the *reason of it* was (very probably) some of my previous git commands on that branch, which apparently caused disabling the tracking of the upstream by this branch. (By default after checking out any branch created with Jira the branch **is** tracking the upstream, hence NO additional commands/options are needed for `git push`.)

As a result (solution):

1. I've changed the name of the branch caused the issue from `XXX` to `XXX_01`.
2. `git checkout XXX` => add changes (via `git stash apply stash@{0}`) => `git commit`.
3. `git push` (with NO additional commands/options) and it worked as expected.

P.S. If anyone knows how it was possible to *unintentionally* disable the tracking of the upstream by the branch (created with Jira), please let us know.

Comment: The local branch is not tracking the upstream branch, you should do `git push -u <remote-name>/xxx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the local branch is not tracking the upstream. This can be verified by running `git branch -vv`. If the local branch has no listed upstream, then run `git push -u origin XXX`.

Comment: Thanks, @RadioSilence for the `git branch -vv` command! It helped me to see that "the local branch is not tracking the upstream". And the _reason of it_ was (very probably) some of my previous git commands on that branch, which apparently caused disabling the tracking of this branch.

Comment: @pmor: Git says that "branch X is tracking Y" if the *upstream* of X is set to Y. Each branch has one upstream—or, optionally, *no* upstream—and the upstream of a branch can either be any remote-tracking name, or any local ordinary branch name. For instance, `master` would normally have `origin/master` as its upstream. The `git branch` command has two options, `--set-upstream-to` and `--unset-upstream`, to let you change the upstream setting of any branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sourcetree as your interface to push your changes to bitbucket server, click on terminal button. Then run the following command with the remote-branch name to which the changes needs to be pushed.
`git branch --set-upstream <remote-branch>`